# Function for changing a column value in all tables in one schema

Tags: postgresql, function, call

I would appreciate it if you could let me know why my code doesn't do anything ? I use PostgreSQL 12.
I want to create a function to change an specific column's value among all tables in a schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_cols(_sch text,_col text, _old int, _new int)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE   
   _tbl text;-- table_name
BEGIN
  -- Loop over tables
FOR _tbl IN
   SELECT quote_ident(table_name)  
    FROM   information_schema.columns
    WHERE  table_schema = _sch  -- name of schema
    AND    column_name = _col  -- name of column
LOOP
RAISE NOTICE '%',
   EXECUTE 
 
      'UPDATE ' || _tbl || ' SET _col = new_id  WHERE  _col = old_id';

END LOOP;

RETURN _tbl;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Call: 
SELECT update_cols('','column_name', 10, 13);
```

Comment: Several issues: 1) `_col` is an identifier like `_tbl` and needs to be handled in same way. 2) I'm assuming `new_id` and `old_id` are really supposed to be `_new` and `_old`. The better solution is found here [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), particular Example 43.1. Quoting Values in Dynamic Queries. I would use the [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) option, it is a little easier to follow.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver

 -- CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_cols(_sch text,_col text, _old int, _new int)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE   
   _tbl text;-- table_name
BEGIN
  -- Loop over tables
FOR _tbl IN
   SELECT quote_ident(table_name)  
    FROM   information_schema.columns
    WHERE  table_schema = _sch  -- name of schema
    AND    column_name = _col  -- name of column
LOOP
      EXECUTE format('UPDATE' ||_tbl|| 'SET '||_col||' = $1 WHERE' ||_col||' = $2')
   USING _new, _old;

END LOOP;

RETURN _tbl;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: Still not working and returns null

Comment: Add your changes to the question and format.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, thanks to the help of [@Adrian Klaver's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70510378/function-for-changing-a-column-value-in-all-tables-in-one-schema/70512937#comment124641133_70510378).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_cols(_sch text, _old int, _new int)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE   
   _tbl text;-- table_name
BEGIN
  -- Loop over tables
FOR _tbl IN
   SELECT quote_ident(table_name)  
    FROM   information_schema.columns 
    WHERE  column_name = 'col_name' and TABLE_Schema = _sch
 
    -- name of column
LOOP
      EXECUTE format('UPDATE ' ||_tbl|| ' SET  col_name = $1 WHERE  col_name= $2') USING _new, _old;

END LOOP;

RETURN _tbl;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77729247/estimate-each-company-size-by-calculating-row-counts-per-table-per-company-id is still not very good and has been closed. Asking for "any ideas" isn't really a question. You need to put more effort in describing your data, give sample data, the calculation, and the result on that sample data. Then we'd have a fighting chance to help you. If you edit the question I'll vote to open.